# How to select specific users who can only grant acces?

Tags: facebook, authentication

Is it possible to select specific Facebook users (based on an ID?) that are able to view the content of your website, after logging in?

E.g. I only want specific persons that are able to view the content that is available on the website.

I'm looking forward to your responses!

Answer (score 0):

You can define test users for sandbox mode, but i'm getting the impression that's not what you're talking about.

If it's a production setting:

You should have some sort of storage of user_ids that are allowed to see the content. In your code (Server or Client side, preferably server so that the content isn't in the page source) you should check to see if they have a valid Facebook session and if its a `user_id` you can recognize as valid.